# App\Models\ must return a relationship instance

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run some dynamic method calls based on the value of a database field. Some context: I have a model `Anniversary` and I want to display all upcoming anniversaries within the next x days. An anniversary has a `date` and a `frequency`. For example, monthly, quarterly, etc. Based on the frequency, I want to check for each anniversary if it is upcoming.

Here is my code so far:

```
$anniversaries = auth()->user()->anniversaries()->get();

$test = $anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {
    $method = Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel();
    return ${$anniversary->$method}() == true;
});

dd($test);
```

The above works, when in the actual method I `dd()` something. But when returning true or false, I get the error:

```
App\Models\Anniversary::monthly must return a relationship instance
```

And in my model I just have a few methods like below, for testing:

```
public function monthly()
{
    return true;
}

public function quarterly()
{
    return false;
}
```

My only question is, I want to understand why I am getting this error and ofcourse any pointers in the right direction to get what I want to work. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try using `$anniversary->$method()`? This way it doesn't invoke a magic method that is caught by the model class

Comment: I did but then I get `Method name must be a string `

Comment: Could you cast method name to a string like this? `$method = (string) (Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel());`

Comment: That worked! Thanks, if you make an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line creates an `Illuminate\Support\Str` object instead of a string. This causes the `Method name must be a string` error.

```
$method = Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel();
```

You can fix this by manually casting it to a string and invoking it directly:

```
$test = $anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {
    $method = (string) (Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel());
    return $anniversary->$method() == true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Throwing in my 2 cents for this as well. The `Str::of()`, which are "Fluent Strings" added in Laravel 7.x return an instance of `Stringable`:

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Stringable.html

For example:

```php
dd(Str::of('monthly')->camel());
Illuminate\Support\Stringable {#3444
  value: "monthly"
}
```

To get the `value` of this, as a `string` and not an `object`, you can cast it (as shown in MaartenDev's answer), or call the `__toString()` method:

```php
dd(Str::of('monthly')->camel()->__toString());
"monthly"
```

In your code example, that would simply be:

```php
$method = Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel()->__toString();
return $anniversary->{$method}() == true;
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `Str::camel()` function to bypass this `Stringable` class:

```php
$method = Str::camel($anniversary->frequency);
return $anniversary->{$method}() == true;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-camel-case

Hope that helps clear up some confusion

Comment: Thanks a lot, helps me understand some things better yeah!

Comment: No problem! I was confused why the `->camel()` function wasn't returning a `String`, especially since the documentation for Fluent Strings suggests that it would  Figured I'd share what I found. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you have issue in this part `${$anniversary->$method}()`. if you access a function like property laravel models thinks its relation function.
so replace with `$anniversary->{$method}()`

try this one

```
$anniversaries = auth()->user()->anniversaries()->get();

$test = $anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {
    $method = Str::of($anniversary->frequency)->camel();
    return $anniversary->{$method}() == true;
});

dd($test);
```

Comment: Tried this but got this error `Method name must be a string`